# need to replace a link in content pulled with file_get_contents & base url

Tags: preg-replace, file-get-contents, radix

I am using `file_get_contents` to pull content from an external page. I then use a base tag to fix all broken links and paths. This works perfectly, However, I have javascript tabs in that page with anchor tags that look like this `href="#"`. Problem is, the tab urls are also affected by the base url tag. When you click on it, it opens the tab but also sends you right back to the external page. Can I use a `preg_replace` to replace all `href="#"` with `href="http://domain.com/page.php#"` to fix the tab links? How will I add it to this code of mine?

```
<?php
$url = 'http://www.externaldomain.com';
$data = file_get_contents($url);
$data = '<head><base href='.$url.' target="_blank" /></head>'.$data;
echo $data;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$data = preg_replace('/\bhref="#"/', 'href="http://domain.com/page.php#"', $data);
```

Just replace the `href="#"` attributes with your desired ones.